# Como faço para o navegador não armazenar cache de imagem com HTML ou PHP?

Tags: php, html, imagem, navegador-de-internet, cache

Estou criando uma página web que é praticamente só imagem, cada dia troco as imagens do página mas o nome delas continua o mesmo. O navegador está guardando muito cache e cada vez que atualizo as imagens elas não mudam visualmente se você já acessou a página no navegador.

Answer (score 11):

### Solução 1 - Servindo as imagens via PHP:

Esta é uma solução para servir imagens de maneira a não ficarem no cache do navegador, setando os headers apropriados via PHP:

```php
<?php
   header( 'Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' );
   header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
   header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
   header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );

   header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
   readfile( 'minhaimagem.jpg' );
?>
```

Trocando o `minhaimagem.jpg` por:

```php
   readfile( '/caminho/para/imagem'.$_GET['img'] );
```

Você pode usar URLs neste formato, por exemplo:

```php
http://example.com/nocache.php/foto12.jpg
```

> Esta é uma simplificação para ilustrar os passos básicos. Certifique-se de fazer uma verificação extra no PHP para não dar acesso a outros arquivos do servidor.

### Solução 2 - Alterando SRC via PHP:

Se as imagens só precisam ser atualizadas na sua página, pode fazer os `src` assim:

```php
echo '<img src="/link/para/imagem.jpg?'.date("YmdHis").'">';
```

Desta forma, a cada segundo a *query string* dos links mudará, forçando uma releitura, porém, sempre apontando para os mesmos caminhos de arquivo no servidor.

Comment: Pergunta órfã. Usuário vista 21/10/2014. Nesse caso a pergunta fica assim até a eternidade @Bacco?

Comment: @durtto faz parte. Nem tudo vai ter accept, mas quem pesquisar pra resolver o mesmo problema, vai achar as respostas :)

Answer (score 3):

Eu recomendo usar o [`filemtime(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) com o `?`, semelhante ao [exemplo do @Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21354/3635), ele retorna a última da de atualização do arquivo, assim o cache só será atualizado se houver mesmo modificações nele:

```
<?php
//Pasta aonde ficam as imagens
define('ABSOLUTE_PATH', '/home/user/project/');
?>

<img src="/link/para/imagem.jpg?<?php echo filemtime(ABSOLUTE_PATH . 'link/para/imagem.jpg'); ?>">
```

E desta maneira você ainda vai poder se beneficiar do cache.

Também existe a possibilidade de usar um `mod_expires` do Apache pra definir um tempo de cache, por exemplo um dia a partir da última atualização.

Primeiro crie um arquivo chamado `.htaccess` na pasta aonde se localizam as imagens ou na raiz e coloque este conteudo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ExpiresByType image/gif "modification plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "modification plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType image/png "modification plus 1 day"
</IfModule>
```

O `ExpiresByType` serve para definir o cache pelo mimetype do arquivo, no caso usei `image/gif`, `image/jpeg` e `image/png` para os tipos `.gif`, `.jpeg` e `.png` respectivamente. O `modification` indica que o cache é gerado a partir da última atualização do arquivo, como no seu caso uma vez por dia você altera os arquivos, o `plus 1 day` soma um dia ao `modification`, assim teremos o cache de um dia.