# Como trabalhar com arquivos e banco de dados de forma que seja possível consistir

Tags: php, mysql

Em um sistema onde se trabalha com uploads de arquivos sendo necessário consistir os links desses arquivos no banco de dados, qual é a melhor abordagem para fazê-lo?

**Exemplo:** Um sistema de cadastro onde é necessário enviar foto do usuário e possibilitando sua edição (reenviar a foto, por exemplo). Como o sistema lidaria com o fato de que é necessário apagar a foto antiga e substituí-la pela atual?

Eu penso que, para atualizar a foto:

- O sistema precisa fazer upload da nova foto;
- O sistema precisa fazer atualização do link da foto no banco de dados;
- O sistema apagar a foto antiga.

E, se algo der errado em algum desses passos, como garantir que o usuário não fique sem foto ou que não haja acúmulo de fotos não utilizadas?

O banco de dados MySQL possui transações que ajudam a lidar com isso, mas o sistema de arquivos não...

Answer (score 2):

Sobre atualizar uma foto pessoalmente diria (sendo um chute de minha parte) que as fotos atualizadas nunca devem conter o mesmo nome, se for web, ou então na parte PHP (que é o seu caso) ajustar as URLs baseado no tempo de atualização (sobrescrita da nova foto na antiga após o upload, que é algo que vai obter baseado no próprio sistema operacional, o PHP já contêm isto, que é o `filemtime(<localização do arquivo>)`), como exemplo que sugeri em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169846/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105171/3635

Desta forma poderia reaproveitar o mesmo nome e ao mesmo tempo contornar o cache das fotos no navegador para o cliente.

---

Sobre deletar uma foto do sistema de arquivos você poderia é claro fazer um `SELECT` no momento, pegar o caminho da foto, então executar o `DELETE`, então se o delete for executado com sucesso pegaria o caminho obtido anteriormente e executaria o `unlink`, se o `unlink` falhar, executaria o rollback no banco (o que acho que na verdade é dispensável conforme a próxima sugestão), ficaria algo como (é apenas **hipotético**):

```
$id = <ID DA FOTO AQUI>;
$foto = null;
$pasta = '/foo/bar/baz/fotos/'; //Pasta aonde se localiza as fotos

$mysqli->autocommit(false); //DESLIGA O autocommit

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT `id`, `foto` FROM `fotos` WHERE id=?')){
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $foto = $row['foto'];
    }

    $stmt->close();
}

if ($foto && $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('DELETE FROM `fotos` WHERE id=?')){
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);

    $deletado = $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();

    if (!$deletado) {
        echo 'Falha ao deletar do banco';
    } elseif (unlink($pasta . $foto)) {
        //Se falhar ao deletar da pasta então executamos o rollback
        $mysqli->rollback();

        echo 'Falha ao deletar da pasta';
    }
}
```

### Separando os "processos"

Apesar de pensar na possibilidade anterior de "invalidar" (deletar) arquivos de imediato como no exemplo acima, creio que um meio menos "hard" seria deixar este processo ocorrer a parte, pelo fato de um arquivo poder estar sendo usado por sistemas de *cache back-end* das páginas aonde se apresenta a imagem/resource, se invalidar o arquivo de imediato isso poderia ocasionar efeitos colaterais, então a sugestão seria simplesmente criar um "processo" (não relacionado a *threads*) a parte que verifique arquivos que não estão mais em uso, assim você poderia eliminar vários arquivos de forma "agendada" consumindo coisas especificas apenas uma vez:

- Como a própria execução do script, que ao invés de eliminar um a um eliminaria vários
- Gravação e leitura do disco apenas de uma vez (apesar disto ser muito relativo e eu realmente não posso afirmar que vai ser melhor apagar vários ao invés de um a um)

A principal vantagem neste caso é que você teria uma garantia que só pegaria o que realmente não consta no banco, claro que se você tiver um sistema que reaproveita nomes de fotos isso com certeza poderia ocasionar um problema de "condição corrida" ou apenas um problema de "inconsistência", então pra isto funcionar bem as fotos nunca devem conter nomes repetidos, mesmo que uma antiga já tenha sido removida

Supondo que executou diversos `DELETE`s durante a "jornada de trabalho" (de quem usa o seu sistema), então em um horário mais ocioso algo com um **CRON** ou algo semelhante, executaria o processo de limpeza, pegando um range de arquivos e checando se existem no banco com [`NOT IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-in), então o que retornou poderia executar o `unlink()`, se forem muitas fotos talvez estabelecer um limite e salvar o ultimo checado, e executando novamente o processo a partir da próxima após o "range".

Não posso afirmar com certeza que é a melhor saída, mas em questões de cache de páginas que ainda precisariam de recursos antigos seria uma forma de minimizar o problema, isso depende muito do que você pretende fazer.

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é você gerar no sistema um UID (id unico) e salvar essa imagem no diretório com este UID, para evitar que páginas salvas em cache não atualizem a imagem quando na verdade a imagem precisa ser atualizada, com um UID sempre o browser vai receber a imagem unica, e pode armazena-la em cache.
Quanto ao HTML gerado, defina nos headers onde a imagem possa ser requisitada, com novo nomo, para expirar em X tempo, ou para não fazer cache dela.

Na verdade, tudo depende do numero de requisições por segundo que esse sistema vai ter, e de como ele vai ser cacheado, se você explicar te auxilio num script, mais passa mais detalhes de como pretende fazer isso.

Answer (score -2):

Se você utiliza banco de dados, é possível fazer tudo isso em um bloco `transaction` do banco de dados, quando houver alguma falha em algum dos passos anteriores, é só efetuar um `rollback`. Caso contrário, `commit`.

Se você utiliza banco de dados não relacional, deveria fazer tudo utilizando atomic operations.

Comment: Se a remoção da foto antiga falhar, eu poderei fazer `rollback` no banco de dados, porém terei um arquivo sobressalente da foto que foi enviada. Eu posso tentar apagá-la, mas essa operação pode falhar e começar a ter acúmulo de arquivos desnecessários. O que posso fazer nessa situação?

Comment: O que você pode fazer é criar uma rotina (cron) que vai rodar (1x a cada n tempo) procurando por arquivos que tiveram falha ao excluir/inserir. Você pode fazer esse gerenciamento via banco de dados também.